# Decompiled .class file in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got problem during adding library into Android Studio project.

I add `jar` file to directory `libs`. I clicked *Add as library* and the problem is that when I try to run project, it fails.
The problem is **`decompiled .class file bytecode version 51.0 (Java 7)`**.
Error in Android Monitor is `NoClassDefFound`.

What I got for now, is that I should have java files, but I have .`class` files.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: That is not you error look in Android Monitor tab for it and post it here.

Comment: The error is NoClassDefFound

Comment: Try to sync the project.

Comment: Where did you put the jar file?? The exact payh

Comment: I tried to sync and I can use import package and all of classed from it, but problem comes when I try to run project

I put jar file into libs, which is located in app directory

Comment: Verify the app gradle file. Do you include the library?

Comment: If you ask about dependency, yes automatically was added compile files 'libs\libname'

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem just using Java Decompiler and adding new java files to project.